# Datetime To Unix timestamp

Tags: php, timestamp

Is there anyone sitting on a PHP function to convert a date of format 0000-00-00 00:00:00(datetimesql) to unix timestamp?

Answer (score 45):

To do this in PHP 5.2 you can do this:

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
echo $datetime->format('U');
```

A newer way to do this as of PHP 5.3 is:

```
$datetime = new DateTime();
echo $datetime->getTimestamp();
```

Answer (score 26):

Another option as you have tagged this question with SQL: the MySQL functions `FROM_UNIXTIME` and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` -> [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html)

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(datetime_column) FROM table
```

This usually is faster than a PHP function call.

Comment: I was asking myself the same question... :-) Always try to get the data out of the database as well as possible, as MySQL will always be faster than PHP.

Comment: I don't think the SQL stuff was in the question when I downvoted this - maybe the edit was during the 5 minute window where it doesn't appear in the edit history?   Down-vote reversed.

Comment: not that the user specified MySQL, and the UNIX_TIMESTAMP() function is not a standard SQL function...

Comment: Alnitak has a valid point, there are a lot of assumptions concerning whether a DB is involved or not wvanbergen. What if he's grabbing timestamps from filenames?

Comment: Timestamps from files already are in unix timestamp format when using PHP functions, the question is tagged SQL and the presented date format is exactly like MySQL returns datetime values. I am not saying this is the only options or the best option, just that it is another approach.

Comment: No. No. Don't generate a call to the SQL server just to convert data. If you need this as part of a query - ok, but getting this trivial information out of process is BAD BAD BAD.

Answer (score 10):

@bartek - As you noted, PHP's [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime) function is perfect for this. It can handle most common date formats, including strings like "tomorrow" or "+5 months".

Comment: Note that because it can handle so many formats, it is really slow. Do not use it if you are going to call it often.

Comment: yup, in fact the manual doesn't actually say whether this particular date-time format is supported.  That's why I recommended strptime() instead.

Comment: I actually wrapped a website around the strtotime() function in case it helps anyone: www.unixstamp.com

Answer (score 6):

I have a solution for you right here:

```
/* From MySQL datetime to Unix Timestamp 2003-12-30 23:30:59 -> 1072834230 */
function convertMysqlDateTimeToUnixTimeStamp($date) {
    $yr=strval(substr($date,0,4));
    $mo=strval(substr($date,5,2));
    $da=strval(substr($date,8,2));
    $hr=strval(substr($date,11,2));
    $mi=strval(substr($date,14,2));
    $se=strval(substr($date,17,2));
    return mktime($hr,$mi,$se,$mo,$da,$yr);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `strptime()` to parse the time and turn it into a structured array.

Then pass the results of that into the `mktime()` function to get a UNIX timestamp.

Comment: dunno - I'm 99% sure the question didn't mention SQL when I posted this answer

Answer (score -3):

Encapusulating wvanbergen's solution into a function (for your convenience)

```
//Convert SQL datetime to unixtime -- by johnboiles
function datetimeToUnixtime($datetime){
    $result = mysql_query("select unix_timestamp('$datetime')");
    $unixtime = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    return $unixtime[0];
}
```

Comment: this implies going to the database twice. wvanbergen's solution was meant to be applied to the where the data is fetched from the db in the first place.