# Find the difference between two dates using PHP?

Tags: php

I have two dates of the form:

```
Start Date: 2013-05-19 
End Date: 2013-05-21
```

Now I need to find the difference between these two in the following form:

```
2013-05-20
2013-05-21
```

How can I do this in PHP?

Comment: why do you need a date as a difference ?

Comment: Because i need those date for query data in database .

Answer (score 0):

this should help
converting iso to unix:
http://www.laughing-buddha.net/php/dates
[Most efficient way to convert a ISO Date into Unix timestamp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/688720/most-efficient-way-to-convert-a-iso-date-into-unix-timestamp)

you could then subtract one date from the other, divide by 3600 and end up with the difference in days, if i understood the question properly

Answer (score 0):

This

```
$startDate = strtotime($date1);
$endDate = strtotime($date2);

$dates = array();

for($x = $startDate, $x <= $endDate; $x+=86400){
    $dates[] = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($x));
}
```

should give you what you want.

Comment: how can result like this ?2013-05-20 and 2013-05-21

Comment: sorry misunderstood the question ....

Comment: updated the answer to reflect what I understand the question to be now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

`$date_difference = strtotime('2013-05-21') - strtotime('2013-05-19');`

That'll give you the seconds between the two dates. If you want that in days, just divide by 86400.

You can also use [date_diff](http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) if using PHP 5.3+.

Comment: how can result like this ?2013-05-20 and 2013-05-21

Comment: Based on your comment about needing this for querying a database... why not just use BETWEEN '2013-05-20' AND '2013-05-21'?

Answer (score 0):

Use can utilize [`DatePeriod`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) class

```php
$begin = new DateTime( '2013-05-19 + 1 day' );
$end = new DateTime( '2013-05-21 + 1 day' );
$interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

foreach($daterange as $date){
    echo $date->format("Y-m-d") . "<br>";
}
```

Output:

```
2013-05-20
2013-05-21
```

**[Codepad example](http://codepad.viper-7.com/WMvNrr)**